# how to write ( A after max time B ) in CEP( Fusion ) Drools

Tags: drools, rule-engine, business-rules, drools-fusion

What is the best way to write a condition in drools CEP to infer ( A after max time B )
Example :

```
a : new A();
b : new B( this after [1m] )
```

The above example is not my need.

I need this :

```
a : new A();
b : new B( this after a , b.timestamp - a.timestamp <= 60000)
```

So i reformulate the question. Is another way to obtain the same result with less instructions ?

Thanks

Comment: If neither of my proposals fits your bill you need to be more verbose, editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit* after clarification of Q

$a: A()
   $b: B( this after[ 0s, 60s ] $a )

This fires if B comes after A but not later than 60 seconds.